# SmartWatch(circular) layout in an Android App ? (Not AndroidWear)

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os, sony-smartwatch

I've been searching all day long for this, haven't found anything that fits what I'm trying to do.

I've bought a SmartWatch (KW88), which runs an Android 5.1 (NOT ANDROID WEAR) and I want to optimize some apps I've been developing lately.

The question is: is there any way to create a "Circular Layout" in Android Studio that fits perfectly on my SmartWatch?

Thank you.

EDIT:
I've tried to change the preview to a Rounded one but it stills working with a regular layout (squared)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular layouts, assume it's squared and assume visible part gonna be the center circle.

[image: something like this]

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue. The layout would still be squared and It wouldn't change at all.